# python.exe crashes when using matplotlib

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, matplotlib, windows-7-x64

This is what I did:

- Installed Enthought Canopy latest version, 64-bit, academic license
- Configured Canopy as default python interpreter
- Downloaded and installed Eclipse platform 4.2, 64-bit version
- Installed PyDev
- Configured PyDev to be used with Canopy by auto-config
- Created a new project and copy-pasted this code:

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
  plt.title("Simple Plot")
  plt.show()
  ```

And this is what I get:

[image]

I use Windows 7 Home premium, 64-bit.
I tried the code on Spyder and it worked fine. It only happens with Pytools and PyDev.

Comment: contact your network administrator ;)

Comment: I think you have did something wrong during installation, try to reinstall again